# Zoom Image In UICollectionViewCell When Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, photo-gallery

I want to implement some features that work like native photo gallery app in iOS. The features are **Zoom In** the image when selected, swipe left or right to see other images in Zoom In mode, **Zoom Out** when back button is clicked. I know there are many third party library that work like charm, but i want to learn something new, something i'm curious about.

I am curios about the concept how this is implemented. I can guess the Zoom In and Zoom Out features which i have done this 2. My problem is how can i swiping left or right to view others images when it is zoom. From what i know, i should be in different ViewController when it is zoomed, so should i have another CollectionView in this ViewController? Furthermore, when we swiped to another image and clicked back button, the image is exactly Zoom Out to the image, that how native iOS photo Library work.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you should create a seperate viewController for the display of a single photo - using `custom uiviewcontroller transitions` you can achieve pretty much every kind of effect you want if you are willing to invest enough time and brain power.

Comment: Adding to @luk's comment... you can load images into uiscrollview with pagination, it will easier to browse image left n right.